# Laravel VueJS Share data between pages

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

In my first page I populate my vue model with some data:

```
data: { ... }
```

Now lets say that I click on a link that takes me to a second page `/user`

Is there any way I can pass the data from my Vue model to the Vue model in the next page?

Comment: I suggest you look for state management in VueJs or Vuex, learn how that works and you're gonna get exactly what you want.

Comment: You say click on a link, is that a normal <a> tag or you are using <router-link>